# jquery - returning a value from function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, return-value, javascript-framework

say I have the following function:

```
function checkPanes() {
    activePane = '';
    var panels = $("#slider .box .panel");

    panels.each(function() {

    //find the one in visible state.
    if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
    activePane = $(this).index()+1;
    console.log(activePane);
    }

    });
} //END checkPanes();
```

Ideally, I'd like to **call** on this function elsewhere (most likely from another function),
and retrieve the value I am currently outputting to console.

(example ..)

```
function exampleCase() {
    checkPanes(); //evidently, does not return anything. 
    //Ideally, I want the numerical value, being output to console in above function.
}
```

Thanks in advance! All suggestions / comments are well appreciated.
Cheers

Comment: Have you tried `return activePane;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget everyone who says `return activePane` since they didn't see it's in a jQuery `each` loop. Won't work.

I'd suggest restructuring your selector.  The selector you should be using is: `$("#slider .box .panel:visible")`. This will cut out your each loop entirely. For instance you could restructure the code as follows:

```
function checkPanes() {
    return $("#slider .box .panel:visible").index();
}

function exampleCase() {
    var visiblePane = checkPanes();

    // ... do something with the index
}
```

I'd suggest just using the selector in-line rather than making a new function, but that's a matter of taste, especially if you have to select the same thing in multiple places.

Comment: It may be in a loop, but since the comment suggests we're looking for the /one/ pane in visible state, once we've found it, we can drop out of the loop.

Comment: this is a simplified version of what I'm trying to accomplish.. Thanks!

Comment: YES! DUH! so simple... I couldnt get this simple answer any where else... *short answer*: if you structure your function like a var like `var data = get_data()` instead of `get_data()` then you can use the data that you got in that same function.

Answer (score 4):

Just noticed the loop; looks like what you may want to return is an array of all active panels (since in theory there could be more than one).

```
function checkPanes() {
    activePanes = [];
    var panels = $("#slider .box .panel");

    panels.each(function() {

    //find the one in visible state.
    if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
    activePane.push($(this).index()+1);
    console.log(activePane);
    }

    });
    return activePanes;
}
```

If you know there will only ever be one active, you can go back to your original approach and just add `return activePane` after the `console.log`.

Comment: I think so yes.. (I am fairly new to all this) - My next question then, how would I log to console, the 'return' value of that function? 
Or use that return value elsewhere? (maybe create a new variable based on the returned value) - Cheers!

Comment: If, in your other function, you do something like `var activePanes=checkPanes();` you will have the return value put into a local variable and can use it as you like (or log it).

Answer (score 0):

Just switch your console line to a return statement:

```
function checkPanes() {
    activePane = '';
    var panels = $("#slider .box .panel");

    panels.each(function() {

    //find the one in visible state.
    if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
        activePane = $(this).index()+1;
        return activePane; // Return the value and leave the function
    }

    });
} //END checkPanes();
```

To call:

```
function exampleCase() {
    var thepane = checkPanes(); //evidently, does not return anything. 
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's as easy as using `return activePane;`

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
function checkPanes() {
  activePane = '';
  var panels = $("#slider .box .panel");

  panels.each(function() {

  //find the one in visible state.
  if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
  activePane = $(this).index()+1;
  }

  });
  return activePane;
} //END checkPanes();
```

and this:

```
function exampleCase() {
   var myval=checkPanes(); //evidently, does not return anything. 
   console.log(myval);
```

}

Comment: ahh ok, so you have to pass the function to a variable, before retrieving it's value for logging to console, etc.
Thank you!

Comment: You don't always need to. But, most other answers have your original function returning early which could be quite bad (almost certainly not in this case, but might be now or in the future). What I have is "safer" than most of the others which is why I'm using the variable.

Answer (score 0):

you have to return something inside the first function to manipulate it inside the second:

```
function checkPanes() {
    activePane = '';
    var panels = $("#slider .box .panel");
    //create a return array
    visiblePanels = [];
    panels.each(function() {

    //find the one in visible state.
    if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
    activePane = $(this).index()+1;
    //add the result to the returnb array
    visiblePanels[] = activePane
    }
    });
    // return results
    return visiblePanels;
}

function exampleCase() {
    var thepane = checkPanes();
    //now it has all the visible panels that were founded in the other function
    // you can access them with thepane[0] or iterate on them

}
```

I think this is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your code and just add a return if you want to use the values somewhere else

```
function checkPanes() {
 activePane = '';
 var panels = $("#slider .box .panel");

  panels.each(function() {

  //find the one in visible state.
  if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
  activePane = $(this).index()+1;
  console.log(activePane); //Logs to console.
  return activePane; //Returns value also.
}

});
}
```

So in here you can either use the returned value or just have it log to console. Thats how i understood your question

```
function exampleCase() {
    checkPanes(); //Now it will still write in console. but you dont need to use the return

    alert(checkpanes()); //Would write it to console and to an alert!
}
```

But make sure you return string - or convert to string if you want to disaply it somewhere as text.